# Flash memory range on STM32F429II

Tags: stm32, memory, flash, stm32f4, non-volatile-memory

I am reading the STM32F429II [data sheet](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00071990.pdf) and looking at page 84, which shows the memory mapping. The chip has 2MB of internal flash memory, but the data sheet is general for all STM32F427xx/STM32F429xx chips.

I can see that internal flash memory range is from 0x0800 0000 to 0x081FF FFFF, which gives a maximum of 0x1FF FFFF = 2MB.

It also says that the STM32F4 devices with 2MB of internal flash has its memory divided in two banks of 1 MB each. This means it is possible to execute code from one bank, while at the same time erase/read/write from the other without halting the code execution (if I have understood it correctly).

On the specific chip I mentioned, is it safe to assume that the start address of bank 2 (program executes by default on bank1 I assume) is 0x100 0000? Where can I find this information? I have not seen it in the data sheet or the reference manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For greater detail on anything STM32F4 related you should refer to the [STM32F4 Reference Manaul](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00031020.pdf) - it tells you everything you could ever need to know about anything.

For instance, in section 3, it tells you:

[image]

So you can see than bank 1 is 0x08000000 to 0x080FFFFF and bank 2 is 0x08100000 to 0x081FFFFF.

Comment: I was not aware that this manual existed. It was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!